# How to reload or re-render the entire page using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, reload, rerender

After rendering the entire page based on several user contexts and having made several `$http` requests, I want the user to be able to switch contexts and re-render everything again (resending all `$http` requests, etc). If I just redirect the user somewhere else, things work properly:

```
$scope.on_impersonate_success = function(response) {
  //$window.location.reload(); // This cancels any current request
  $location.path('/'); // This works as expected, if path != current_path
};

$scope.impersonate = function(username) {
  return auth.impersonate(username)
    .then($scope.on_impersonate_success, $scope.on_auth_failed);
};
```

If I use `$window.location.reload()`, then some of the `$http` requests on `auth.impersonate(username)` that are waiting for a response get cancelled, so I can't use that. Also, the hack `$location.path($location.path())` doesn't work either (nothing happens).

Is there another way to re-render the page without manually issuing all requests again?

Comment: As Alvaro Joao says below, you need to use angular-route.js in order to get this to work.  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2770-route-must-be-injected-in-order-to-enable-the-routechangesuccess-event-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs: Reload page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885518/angularjs-reload-page)

Answer (score 409, accepted):

For the record, to force angular to re-render the current page, you can use:

```
$route.reload();
```

According to AngularJS [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route):

> Causes $route service to reload the current route even if $location hasn't changed.
>
> As a result of that, ngView creates new scope, reinstantiates the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, for some reason I seem to get slightly different behavior when I use `$route.reload()` compared to a normal refresh. For example a tab is set to show initially on refresh, but when the reload method seems to reload the page without setting the tab, not sure what the problem is.

Comment: is it possible to reload a specific controller that's not on the actual view or state?

Comment: Does this run filters/services as well? Getting undesired persistent state. Edit: Still upvoted for answering the question correctly & this is super helpful. Thank you

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment below, you should persist data in the controllers and/or local storage only.  Persisting data elsewhere, as you noticed, leads to these annoying bugs hard to fix. That happens because [they're singletons](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#!), so they are instantiated once and never again.

Comment: Remember to inject `$route` to the controller for this to work.

Comment: any way to trigger this inline with a button?

Comment: @andersonvom this gave me the following error, Unknown provider: $routeProvider <- $route

Comment: @alphapilgrim  The ngRoute module is no longer part of the core `angular.js file`. If you are continuing to use `$routeProvider` then you will now need to include `angular-route.js` in your HTML:

Comment: $state.reload() if you using stateProvider

Comment: does this reload also trigger animations like ng-enter ?

Answer (score 321):

`$route.reload()` will reinitialise the controllers but not the services. If you want to reset the whole state of your application you can use:

```
$window.location.reload();
```

This is a [standard DOM method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/location/reload) which you can access injecting the [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) service.

If you want to be sure to reload the page from the server, for example when you are using Django or another web framework and you want a fresh server side render, pass `true` as a parameter to `reload`, as explained in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/location/reload). Since that requires interaction with the server, it will be slower so do it only if necessary

#### Angular 2

The above applies to Angular 1. I am not using Angular 2, looks like the services are different there, there is `Router`, `Location`, and the `DOCUMENT`. I did not test different behaviors there

Comment: It is worth noting that one shouldn't be storing state in the services anyway to require services to be "restarted".

Comment: Who says that? Where is one supposed to store cached data?

Comment: I have stumbled upon lots and lots of bugs due to data being stored in services, making them stateful rather than stateless. Unless we're talking about a caching service (in which case, there would be an interface to flush it), I would keep data out of services and in the controllers.

For instance, one could keep data in localStorage, and use a service to access it.  This would free the service from keeping data directly in it.

Comment: @danza *Where is one supposed to store cached data?* ... a model object? Howver Angular has done a terrible job of naming their MVCS constituents.  I keep injectable model objects via the module.value API.  Then the various APIs I defined on an ng service that alter the model object work more like commands.

Comment: just js method `window.location.reload()` without `$` works for me.

Comment: Sure, that will work, but it is not good practice. See [the documentation about $window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window), the reason for using it is explained in the beginning: *While window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is a global variable. In angular we always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for testing*

Comment: But it won't redo template rendering in Django or other frameworks like Node.js

Comment: @AminahNuraini that should work, passing a parameter to `reload`. I edited the answer in order to include that

Comment: @Danza, it turns out it didn't seem to rerender because the database API takes a little bit longer to update but I already reload. It was solved by putting the reload inside ´then()´

Comment: @danza, $route is part of ng.route.IRouteService??

Comment: @cracker `ngRoute.$route.reload()` in Angular 1.5

Comment: is that ngRoute.$route.reload() required any dependency too ?

Comment: @AnujGupta yes, obviously

Comment: I tried that but it was generating some issues,I did my task from other method.Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I've just added a feature that displays a message in the ionCube24 UI for logged in users if we've just deployed an update and their UI code is now behind and needs refreshing; called from a function on the root scope, this works a treat to let the user trigger an update and reload of the application.

Answer (score 39):

For reloading the page for a given route path :-

```
$location.path('/path1/path2');
$route.reload();
```

Comment: Don't know why but the .reload() method seems not working here. It doesn't realod anything.

Answer (score 29):

If you are using **angular ui-router** this will be the best solution.

```
$scope.myLoadingFunction = function() {
    $state.reload();
};
```

Comment: In my cli project after deployment to shared hosting. When i am reloading my project its giving 404 error to resolve this have used .
If i add 'use hash', then it works with '#', but i don't want this , is there way it can be resolved.

Answer (score 24):

Well maybe you forgot to add "$route" when declaring the dependencies of your Controller:

```
app.controller('NameCtrl', ['$scope','$route', function($scope,$route) {   
   // $route.reload(); Then this should work fine.
}]);
```

Answer (score 9):

Just to reload everything , use window.location.reload(); with angularjs

Check out working example

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">  
<button  ng-click="reloadPage();">Reset</button>
</div>
```

angularJS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.reloadPage = function(){window.location.reload();}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/22324/

Answer (score 7):

If you want to refresh the controller while refreshing any services you are using, you can use this solution:

- *Inject $state*

i.e.

```
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','MyService','$state', function($scope,MyService,$state) {

    //At the point where you want to refresh the controller including MyServices

    $state.reload();

    //OR:

    $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
}
```

This will refresh the controller and the HTML as well you can call it **Refresh or Re-Render**.

Comment: this is for ui router not for angular.

Answer (score 7):

Try one of the following:

```
$route.reload(); // don't forget to inject $route in your controller
$window.location.reload();
location.reload();
```

Answer (score 6):

**Before Angular 2 ( AngularJs )**

Through route

```
$route.reload();
```

If you want reload whole Application

```
$window.location.reload();
```

**Angular 2+**

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location) {}

ngOnInit() {  }

load() {
    this.location.reload()
}
```

Or

```
constructor(private location: Location) {}

ngOnInit() {  }

Methods (){
    this.ngOnInit();
}
```

Comment: FYI - Angular 7: "Property 'reload' does not exist on type 'Location'".

Comment: @Cristina thanks your information. I use this before angular 7

Answer (score 5):

Easiest solution I figured was,

add '/' to the route that want to be reloaded every time when coming back.

eg:

instead of the following

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/About', {
    templateUrl: 'about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl'
  })
```

use,

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/About/', { //notice the '/' at the end 
    templateUrl: 'about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl'
  })
```

Comment: @PardeepJain This worked for me. That is why this is an answer. Did you downvote my answer?

Comment: no not at all, your answer is not so bad to downvote. amazing i don't now why same is not working for me in angular2.

Comment: Perfect solution. Thks!

Comment: This works even if your original path is the root of the application - `/` :O
My route now looks like this: `//`

Comment: In Angular 6 it works after using # same can be used for Angular2 too. think so

Answer (score 4):

I got this working code for removing cache and reloading the page

**View**

```
        <a class="btn" ng-click="reload()">
            <i class="icon-reload"></i> 
        </a>
```

**Controller**

Injectors: **$scope,$state,$stateParams,$templateCache**

```
       $scope.reload = function() { // To Reload anypage
            $templateCache.removeAll();     
            $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, { reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true });
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code without intimate reload notification to the user. It will render the page

```
var currentPageTemplate = $route.current.templateUrl;
$templateCache.remove(currentPageTemplate);
$window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score -9):

I've had a hard fight with this problem for months, and the only solution that worked for me is this:

```
var landingUrl = "http://www.ytopic.es"; //URL complete
$window.location.href = landingUrl;
```

Comment: This is hardly different than doing `$window.location.reload()` which the OP specifically mentions does not work properly in his case.