# How to reload a page using Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a link. When user will click in this link, then the page will be reloaded. I did it by the following way......

**Html**

```
<div data-ng-hide="backHide" class="offset6 pull-right">
     <a href="" data-ng-click="backLinkClick()"><< Back  <br/> <br/></a>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.backLinkClick = function () {
            window.location.reload(false); 
        };
```

In the controller I have used javascript and that seems to me very bad. How can I do it using [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/)

Comment: If you are using routing you can do `$route.reload();`

Comment: No, I am not using routing

Comment: I dont think not using angular is a bad idea here. Simply move your code inside onclick of <a tag: `onclick="window.location.reload(false)"`

Comment: if you have to use `window` you should use the wrapper: `$window`. however, `$route.reload()` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reload or re-render the entire page using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703215/how-to-reload-or-re-render-the-entire-page-using-angularjs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs: Reload page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885518/angularjs-reload-page)

Comment: Hey @AlenaKastsiukavets, can you check the date? Which question has been asked at first?

Comment: @AtishDipongkor I agree, this one is older, but the answers are better for the other question, so it is more useful...

Comment: so you can give it as a useful link. you can not mark my question as a duplicate, can you?? @AlenaKastsiukavets

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Be sure to include the $route service into your scope and do this:

```
$route.reload();
```

See this:

[How to reload or re-render the entire page using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703215/how-to-reload-or-re-render-the-entire-page-using-angularjs)

Comment: I sometimes have to recompile the page without reloading it (e.g. I have a special way of localizing it). Then I just call `$compile(angular.element('whatever div wrapping ng-view')(scope))`

Answer (score 7):

You can also try this, after injecting $window service.

```
$window.location.reload();
```

Comment: I'm not using angular routing and this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need $route defined in your module and change the JS to this.

```
$scope.backLinkClick = function () {
  window.location.reload(); 
};
```

that works fine for me.

Comment: Why so many negative? Any arguments? I understand using this is a bad idea, but just downvote and don't describe why is not better.

Comment: @alexche8 There many things wrong with post. 
First the users says you need $route defined in your module than goes and totally ignores it himself by using window.location.reload which is till an other bad practice in angular apps(use $window wrapper instead of window otherwise your breaking angular abstraction). 
user2975967 is suggestion a bad but working solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.rtGo = function(){
            $window.sessionStorage.removeItem('message');
            $window.sessionStorage.removeItem('status');
        }
```