# AngularJs: Reload page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
<a ng-href="#" class="navbar-brand" title="home" data-translate>PORTAL_NAME</a>
```

I want to reload the page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 270):

You can use the `reload` method of the `$route` service. Inject `$route` in your controller and then create a method `reloadRoute` on your `$scope`.

```
$scope.reloadRoute = function() {
   $route.reload();
}
```

Then you can use it on the link like this:

```
<a ng-click="reloadRoute()" class="navbar-brand" title="home" data-translate>PORTAL_NAME</a>
```

This method will cause the current route to reload. If you however want to perform a full refresh, you could inject `$window` and use that:

```
$scope.reloadRoute = function() {
   $window.location.reload();
}
```

**Later edit (ui-router):**

As mentioned by JamesEddyEdwards and Dunc in their answers, if you are using [angular-ui/ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) you can use the following method to reload the current state / route. Just inject `$state` instead of `$route` and then you have:

```
$scope.reloadRoute = function() {
    $state.reload();
};
```

Comment: This is a good answer if you're desperate to Angularise the reload.

Comment: How can I change this behavior globally instead of adding an action to all links

Comment: @OMGPOP What exactly do you mean by globally for all links?

Comment: i mean, for all links you need to do this. is it possible to config once for all links?

Comment: @AlexandrinRus this give's me the following [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: @AlexandrinRus $route is part of ng.route.IRouteService??

Answer (score 52):

`window` object is made available through `$window` service for [easier testing and mocking](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/window), you can go with something like:

```
$scope.reloadPage = function(){$window.location.reload();}
```

And :

```
<a ng-click="reloadPage"  class="navbar-brand" title="home"  data-translate>PORTAL_NAME</a>
```

As a side note, i don't think $route.reload() actually reloads the page, but [only the route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route).

Comment: I recommend using `$window` instead of `window`.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Would you explain us why ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's best explained by [the `$window` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window), mainly it's because `reloadPage` would be (better) testable when it uses `$window`.

Answer (score 23):

```
 location.reload();
```

Does the trick.

```
<a ng-click="reload()">

$scope.reload = function()
{
   location.reload(); 
}
```

No need for routes or anything just plain old js

Comment: love the simplicity!

Comment: It breaks karma/jasmine tests because it does a page full reload and it is not mockable.
By using the `$window` provider it is possible to mock in tests

Answer (score 14):

Similar to Alexandrin's answer, but using $state rather than $route:

(From JimTheDev's SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25206754/188926).)

```
$scope.reloadState = function() {
   $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
}

<a ng-click="reloadState()" ...
```

Answer (score 9):

If using Angulars more advanced [ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) which I'd definitely recommend then you can now simply use:

```
$state.reload();
```

Which is essentially doing the same as Dunc's answer.

Answer (score 5):

My solution to avoid the infinite loop was to create another state which have made the redirection:

```
$stateProvider.state('app.admin.main', {
    url: '/admin/main',
    authenticate: 'admin',
    controller: ($state, $window) => {
      $state.go('app.admin.overview').then(() => {
        $window.location.reload();
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Angular 2+**

I found this while searching for Angular 2+, so here is the way:

```
$window.location.reload();
```

Comment: this isn't specific to angular, by the way, its javascript way.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by calling the reload() method in JavaScript.

```
location.reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to just use `$route.reload()` (don't forget to inject $route into your controller), but from your example you could just use "href" instead of "ng-href":

```
<a href=""  class="navbar-brand" title="home"  data-translate>PORTAL_NAME</a>
```

You only need to use ng-href to protect the user from invalid links caused by them clicking before Angular has replaced the contents of the {{ }} tags.

Comment: $route is part of ng.route.IRouteService??

Answer (score 1):

On Angular 1.5 - after trying some of the above solutions wanting to reload only the data with no full page refresh, I had problems with loading the data properly. I noticed though, that when I go to another route and then I return back to the current, everything works fine, but when I want to only reload the current route using `$route.reload()`, then some of the code is not executed properly. Then I tried to redirect to the current route in the following way:

```
$scope.someFuncName = function () {
    //go to another route
    $location.path('/another-route');
};
```

and in the module config, add another `when`:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider.when('/first-page', {
         templateUrl: '/first-template',
         controller: 'SomeCtrl'
     }).when('/another-route', {//this is the new "when"
         redirectTo: '/first-page'
     });
}])
```

and it works just fine for me. It does not refresh the whole page, but only causes the current controller and template to reload. I know it's a bit hacky, but that was the only solution I found.

Comment: an easier way might be `var reload = $location.url(); $location.url(''); $timeout(function() { $location.url(reload); });`; no need to create random routes. But it'd be interesting to see what code doesn't re-evaluate for you. It looks like even `redirectTo`s and `resolve` functions [re-execute on a normal `$route.reload()`](http://jsfiddle.net/502jz9fx/1/) (look at the console.log's).

Answer (score 1):

```
<a title="Pending Employee Approvals" href="" ng-click="viewPendingApprovals(1)">
                    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="button_badge">{{pendingEmployeeApprovalCount}}</span>
                </a>
```

and in the controller

```
 $scope.viewPendingApprovals = function(type) {
                if (window.location.hash.substring(window.location.hash.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, window.location.hash.length) == type) {
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $state.go("home.pendingApproval", { id: sessionStorage.typeToLoad });
                }
            };
```

and in the route file

```
.state('home.pendingApproval', {
        url: '/pendingApproval/:id',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/approvals/pendingApprovalList.html',
        controller: 'pendingApprovalListController'
    })
```

So, If the id passed in the url is same as what is coming from the function called by clicking the anchor, then simply reload, else folow the requested route.

Please help me improve this answer, if this is helps. Any, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This took me one month to figure it out why is page not reloading

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by calling the reload() method of the window object in plain JavaScript

```
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to refer the page. Official suggestion

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

[image]