# AngularJS won't refresh the page if the link that is clicked is with the same URL as the current page

Tags: angularjs

I noticed this on two of my projects where I'm using AngularJS, so I'm assuming it's an issue with AngularJS.

Let's say I have a button on the menu that says "Register" and takes me to /account/register page. But, if I'm on the /account/register page, clicking the button won't refresh the page. It's like the button is disabled. This is always happening when the link I want to click has the same URL as the current page I'm on. The URLs are simple `<a href="something1/something2">Link</a>`. How can I remove this behavior?

Comment: do you want to refresh page?

Comment: I just want the link to be clickable, even if it means that it is taking me on the same page as the current one.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem with angular, adding `target="_parent"` attribute to the link made it work.

Comment: Verified with AngularJS v1.4.7.  This fixed the same exact problem I was having inside my navbar, which is included in all my pages via `ng-include`.

Answer (score 2):

For who didn't understand, I have recorded my screen to display this issue. 
Basically, there are somethings wrong of Angular.

[image: Zone not loaded]

1. If we place the navigation outside of the ng-app.
2. The app has already loaded.
3. Then we click again to this navigation.
4. The app will disappear with no reason.

I fixed it by adding `target="_parent"` or `target="_self"` attribute to the anchor tag as answered above.

Check more on [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the current url/state/hash is "/account/register" ... if yes then use reload method of the $route service.

[AngularJs: Reload page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885518/angularjs-reload-page)

Comment: The register link that I'm talking about is not in any Angular Controller, it's just a link in the menu. But, it's under ng-app. This is also happening if the link is under some Angular Controller.

Comment: Then you might need to listen to 'locationchangestart' event of the $route service. Can you please paste a sample snippet?

Comment: I'm not using $routeProvider nor $locationProvider, it's not a single page application.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any reasonable way to check the path inside view, but this could work:
view:

```
<a link-href="path/to/same/location">same location</a>
```

directive:

```
app.directive('linkHref', ['$location', '$route', function ($location, $route) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $element.bind('click', function () {
        if ($location.$$url == $attrs.activeLink) {
          $route.reload();
        } else {
          $location.path($attrs.activeLink);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that if I removed $location (wasn't using anyways) that was listed in a factory the problem went away.