# Clear History and Reload Page on Login/Logout Using Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am new to mobile application development with Ionic. On login and logout I need to reload the page, in order to refresh the data, however, `$state.go('mainPage')` takes the user back to the view without reloading - the controller behind it is never invoked.

Is there a way to clear history and reload the state in Ionic?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Welcome to the framework! Actually the routing in Ionic is powered by [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). You should probably check out [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/angular-js-angular-ui-router-reloading-current-state-refresh-data) to find a couple of different ways to accomplish this.

If you just want to reload the state you can use:

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
```

If you actually want to reload the page (as in, you want to re-bootstrap everything) then you can use:

```
$window.location.reload(true)
```

Good luck!

Comment: I want to bundle all css/js files pulled from remote server in index.html. But I'd prefer to only reload these if there's been a change. How should I structure this?

Comment: Not sure if I understand you @mylord. Are you talking about live reload? Maybe you are interested in the Html5 offline cache / manifest as discussed here: http://tmkmobile.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/html5-offline-solution/ 

I think you might be trying to do something other than the original intent of the question.

Comment: $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
this solution does not works for me.

Comment: @IamStalker can you provide any further information or perhaps a codepen/fiddle/plunk as an example?

Comment: `$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});` doesn't work if `cache:true` (which is the default if cache is omitted) in state definition. Tested in #ionic 1.0.0-RC2 and 1.0.0. See my answer.

Comment: with '$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});' the view gets refreshed but the side menu and the header disappears!

Comment: For me, the first answer gets caught in loop and the second throws an error.

Comment: how to do this in ionic2?

Answer (score 25):

I found that JimTheDev's answer only worked when the state definition had `cache:false` set. With the view cached, you can do `$ionicHistory.clearCache()` and then `$state.go('app.fooDestinationView')` if you're navigating from one state to the one that is cached but needs refreshing.

See my answer here as it requires a simple change to Ionic and I created a pull request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30224972/756177

Comment: Good stuff. I don't actually use this in my ionic app so I appreciate the followup with the caching functionality. Looks like your PR is going to go into 1.0.1. Once that is released I'll make a note in my original post crediting you and prompting people to take a look.

Answer (score 18):

The correct answer:

```
$window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. Could you try to explain why it is the correct answer?

Comment: Because it uses `$window` instead of `window`

Comment: You are correct in that if you go with the .location.reload syntax it makes sense to use $window. I've changed my answer above just so that we're consistent for future readers. The $state.go syntax may be useful as well in certain cases.

Comment: Only this answer has helped me, not the ticked one

Comment: I used to like that approach, but some people reported that it causes infinite loop of reloads on some devices (Android 4.4, Chrome).

Answer (score 18):

I have found a solution which helped me to get it done. Setting `cache-view="false"` on `ion-view` tag resolved my problem.

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
  ....
</ion-view>
```

Comment: disable cache view make a significant lose of performance you should avoid this options. instead you can handle ionicView events. see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192172/force-view-to-reload-in-ionic-framework/33708463#33708463

Comment: @ezain, Could you please let me know how does the performance gets affected?

Comment: @Rajeshwar, when the cache system is enabled, Ionic maintains all DOM generated by the view hidden and when a change view occurs you not need to recalculate the DOM. If you have a heavy DOM and you need to generate it in all transition change you can appreciate lags in the transition animations. If you only reason for disable cache is reload the controller use the ionicView events.

Comment: @ezain, There are so many ways implementing this feature of disabling cache. I tried almost all of them, nothing worked for me. And this one gave me what i need. And i don't see any considerable lagging while loading that page, even though the page is little big. So i preferred this way than the other ways.

Answer (score 11):

Reload the page isn't the best approach.

you can handle state change events for reload data without reload the view itself.

read about **ionicView life-cycle** here:

http://blog.ionic.io/navigating-the-changes/

and handle the event beforeEnter for data reload.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(){
  // Any thing you can think of
});
```

Comment: This seems like the best approach.

Comment: specifically you can check if the state is from cache, and if so, call some of your APIs to refresh it: `$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(scopes, states) {
    if (states.fromCache) { ... }
}`

Comment: @jakub.g if you don't want to cache a view you can disable the cache for this specific view, is more simple.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I need to clear just the view and restart the controller. I could get my intention with this snippet:

```
$ionicHistory.clearCache([$state.current.name]).then(function() {
  $state.reload();
});
```

The cache still working and seems that just the view is cleared.

`ionic --version` says 1.7.5.

Comment: An addendum:  
When the state has parameters, you must define them in view/state identification.  
Check this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/2CaGYpnz

Comment: Erros in your code
Correct version  $ionicHistory.clearCache([$state.current.name]).then(function() {
         $state.reload();

        });

Comment: Just missing a parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions mentioned above worked for a hostname that is different from `localhost`!

I had to add **`notify: false`** to the list of options that I pass to `$state.go`, to avoid calling Angular change listeners, before `$window.location.reload` call gets called. Final code looks like:

`$state.go('home', {}, {reload: true, notify: false});`

**>>> EDIT - $timeout might be necessary depending on your browser >>>**

`$timeout(function () {
        $window.location.reload(true);
      }, 100);`

**<<< END OF EDIT <<<**

More about this on [ui-router reference](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#options).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do refresh page using angularjs when i saw websites i got confused but no code was working for the code then i got solution for reloading page using

```
$state.go('path',null,{reload:true});
```

use this in a function this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to reload the state to make scrollbars work. They did not work when coming through another state - 'registration'. If the app was force closed after registration and opened again, i.e. it went directly to 'home' state, the scrollbars worked. None of the above solutions worked.

When after registration, I replaced:

```
$state.go("home");
```

with

```
window.location = "index.html";
```

The app reloaded, and the scrollbars worked.

Answer (score 0):

The controller is called only once, and you SHOULD preserve this logic model, what I usually do is:

I create a method `$scope.reload(params)`

At the beginning of this method I call `$ionicLoading.show({template:..})` to show my custom spinner

When may reload process is finished, I can call `$ionicLoading.hide()` as a callback

Finally, Inside the button REFRESH, I add `ng-click = "reload(params)"`

The only downside of this solution is that you lose the ionic navigation history system

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload after view change you need to

```
$state.reload('state',{reload:true});
```

If you want to make that view the new "root", you can tell ionic that the next view it's gonna be the root

```
 $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ historyRoot: true });
 $state.go('app.xxx');
 return;
```

If you want to make your controllers reload after each view change

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

.state(url: '/url', controller: Ctl, templateUrl: 'template.html', cache: false)
cache: false ==> solved my problem !

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @ezain reload controllers only when its necessary. Another cleaner way of updating data when changing states rather than reloading the controller is using broadcast events and listening to such events in controllers that need to update data on views.

**Example:** in your login/logout functions you can do something like so:

```
$scope.login = function(){
    //After login logic then send a broadcast
    $rootScope.$broadcast("user-logged-in");
    $state.go("mainPage");
};
$scope.logout = function(){
   //After logout logic then send a broadcast
   $rootScope.$broadcast("user-logged-out");
   $state.go("mainPage");
};
```

Now in your mainPage controller trigger the changes in the view by using the $on function to listen to broadcast within the mainPage Controller like so:

```
$scope.$on("user-logged-in", function(){
     //update mainPage view data here eg. $scope.username = 'John';
});

$scope.$on("user-logged-out", function(){
    //update mainPage view data here eg. $scope.username = '';
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried many methods, but found this method is absolutely correct:

```
$window.location.reload();
```

Hope this help others stuck for days like me with version: angular 1.5.5, ionic 1.2.4, angular-ui-router 1.0.0