# How to prevent white screen when reloading page in Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using AngularJS and the Ionic Framework to build an app. My app needs to have a logout button. When the user presses the logout button, I would like to reload the page so that the app is re-bootstrapped and all cached data is wiped clean. Based on [this StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192172/force-view-to-reload-in-ionic-framework) I should be able to just do `$window.location.reload(true)`. That works fine if I'm just running the app in the browser via `ionic serve`. However, when I run it on an actual device, the screen just goes blank and never comes back. How can I reload/refresh the page on the mobile device without getting a blank screen?

**EDIT: Here's my actual code:**

```
angular.module('login').controller('logoutController', ['$state', '$window', function ($state, $window) {
    $state.go('login');
    $window.location.reload(true);
}]);
```

I'm trying to reload the location after transitioning to the `login` state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above works fine. It turns out that my problem was with how I was transitioning to the `logout` state. If I use `href` on the `ion-item`, then it causes the blank screen issue:

```
<ion-item nav-clear menu-close class="item-icon-left" href="#/logout">
    Logout
</ion-item>
```

However, if I use `ui-sref` on the `ion-item`, then the blank screen does not occur:

```
<ion-item nav-clear menu-close class="item-icon-left" ui-sref="logout">
    Logout
</ion-item>
```

Don't ask me how or why that happens. That's just what I have observed.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested $window.location.reload(true) within my apps' logout function and it works fine (also within the actual app).

In order to solve your problem, please get sure that

1. you added `$window` as dependency in your view's controller
2. you send your user to the apps entry view, by calling 
   `$state.go("your-entry-view")` within your logout function or
3. by defining a fallback state within your `$stateProvider` config:
   `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/your-entry-views-url')`

If that doesn't help, provide us with some more details, like the controller where you are calling the logout function and your state config. Also your console output could help.