# How to refresh a view in ionic

Tags: javascript, view, ionic-framework

I want to refresh a page when I click a button (refresh the data in the page, release the cache) 
The main page I have a list in my main page. there is a function for change the item on the list. but when I change the item and redirect to  main page it show me the previous values until refresh the page, I want to refresh only when I press the button (clear the cache on main page ).
in controller  `$state.go("app.feed");` I wrote this. how do I change it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to reload the state you can use:

```
$state.go($app.feed, {}, {reload: true});

$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
```

you can refer this page :[Clear History and Reload Page on Login/Logout Using Ionic Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192172/force-view-to-reload-in-ionic-framework)

or

Refer this page:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/582

Answer (score 0):

Keep "cache-view" attribute in the view, and it will not cache which always load fresh data

```
<ion-view view-title="Favourite List" cache-view="false">
```