# force view to reload in ionic2 framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view, ionic2

After going through [Clear History and Reload Page on Login/Logout Using Ionic Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192172/force-view-to-reload-in-ionic-framework)

I want to know same question, but for ionic2 using typescript.

On login and logout I need reload the `app.ts`, because there are classes that run libraries on construct.

it would be basically redirect to home and reload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ionic 1

---

I haven't used Ionic 2 but currently i m using Ionic 1.2 and if they are still using ui-router than you can use reload: true in ui-sref

or you can add below code to your logout controller

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
});
```

Angular 2

---

Use

$window.location.reload();

or

location.reload();

Comment: I have already posted link to answers of ionic1.. so this really does not help

Comment: Ok Let me give it a try than will come back to you

Comment: Bro are you using angular 2

Comment: Yes ionic2 comes with angular2

Comment: do you want to write that in answer, so I can accept it as answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105026/discussion-between-siddharth-pandey-and-basit).

Comment: That does not work for Ionic 2, it is different in the new version.

Answer (score 4):

Found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373951/refresh-a-page-in-ionic2), (please note especially the line `this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);` which is by far the simplest solution that I've come across to reload present page for Ionic 2 & 3 and later versions of Angular (mine is 4), so credit due accordingly:

**RELOAD CURRENT PAGE**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ModalController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-example',
  templateUrl: 'example.html'
})
export class ExamplePage {

  public someVar: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private modalCtrl: ModalController) {

  }

  refreshPage() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
  }

}
```

If you want to **RELOAD A DIFFERENT PAGE** please use the following (note `this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ModalController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from'../home/home';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-example',
  templateUrl: 'example.html'
})
export class ExamplePage {

  public someVar: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private modalCtrl: ModalController) {

  }

  directToNewPage() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  }

}
```

Comment: And if i want to refresh a part of page, then how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the `CanReuse` interface, and override the `routerCanReuse` to return `false`. Then, try calling `router.renavigate()`.

Your component should look like this:

```
class MyComponent implements CanReuse {
  // your code here...
  routerCanReuse(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) { 
    return false;
  }
}
```

And then, when you perform login/logout, call:

```
// navigate to home
router.renavigate()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack, but it works.

Wrap the logic that follows your template adjustment in a `setTimeout` and that gives the browser a moment to do the refresh:

```
/* my code which adjusts the ng 2 html template in some way */
setTimeout(function() {
    /* processing which follows the template change */
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

For ionic 2 it works for me when you force page reload by triggering `fireWillEnter` on a view controller

```
viewController.fireWillEnter();
```

Comment: do we need to add import for ionic2 @paulitto

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan yes you'll need to import it from ionic-angular

Answer (score 0):

> Here is what worked for me to ***refresh only current page***-

I am trying to call refreshMe function when I call onDelete from my view page,
See how my page.ts file looks-

```
 export class MyPage {
    lines of code goes here like 
    public arr1: any;
    public arr2: any;

    public constructor(private nav: NavController, navParams: NavParams) {
      this.nav = nav;

      this.arr1 = [];
      this.arr2 = [];
      // console.log("hey array");
    }  

    onDelete() {
       perform this set of tasks...
       ...
       ...
      refreshMe()
    }


    refreshMe() {
      this.nav.setRoot(MyPage);
    }
}
```

**This is just refreshing only current page.**
We can also call this function from view if we need as--

```
<ion-col width-60 offset-30 (click)="refreshMe()">
   ....
   ....
</ion-col>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use these three lines to totally refresh a component

```
let active = this.navCtrl.getActive(); // or getByIndex(int) if you know it
this.navCtrl.remove(active.index);
this.navCtrl.push(active.component);
```

You can use the ionViewWillLeave() to display your splashscreen while component is reloading and then hide it with ionViewDidEnter() once its loaded.

Hope it helps