# Refresh a page in ionic2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2, refresher

Is there a way to refresh only a page i.e. only one screen in ionic2.

I tried :

```
window.location.reload();
```

and

```
location.reload();
```

but it rebuilds the app .. is there a way to refresh only that page (particular screen).

Also tried:

```
<ion-input *ngIf="no_internet === 1" (click)="refresh($event)"></ion-input>
```

in TypeScript:

```
refresh(refresher) {
    console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Async operation has ended');
        refresher.complete();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: can you explain what exactly are you trying to update in your page? when using ionic there are other ways to upload the content, refreshing the page is not recommended

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this code :

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
```

Comment: it removes all previous navigations.

Comment: it's not solution , as @Yawar said, you removes all previous navigations ,

Comment: Removes all navigation. Not a solution

Comment: Try this: Just pop one page and then push that page again. Hope this will help :)

this.navCtrl.pop(); this.navCtrl.push(NewPage);

Comment: To avoid affecting on the navigation, I work around refreshing view by wrapping components ( _product list_) need to be updated in a function and call it on **didLoad**, **add** and **delete** actions

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the ionic refresher, to create a pull to refresh action on the page

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/refresher/Refresher/

Comment: then create a (click)="refresh()" action on the button, and create a refresh method in the ts file

Comment: I request you to look my updated question, can you please suggest where am i wrong.

Comment: Well, usually you'd pass in an $event in the method call in the template, but if you have the 'refresher' variable set up as something earlier in the template, I guess it should work. Otherwise try passing in $event in your template. But do you really need to pass anything in. Could you not just call you ionViewWillEnter() method, or create a method that refreshed the data you need on the page?

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-refresh-current-page/47167/3

Comment: Your ion-list or whatever you're using is getting its' data from an array in your ts file, correct? Then just update that array in your refresh method, and the list will update.

Answer (score 2):

I would do that : (based on @Ahmad Aghazadeh answer)

```
this.navCtrl.push(this.navCtrl.getActive().component).then(() => {
   let index = this.viewCtrl.index;
   this.navCtrl.remove(index);
})
```

=> Push this page once more (loading it again)

=> Remove the page we were on (using index)

Comment: and method `ionViewWillEnter` can be used to manage any preparation for the new loaded view

Answer (score 1):

Example of using ion-refresher in an async function in ionic 3:

in your .html file:

```
<ion-content no-padding >
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
```

and in your .ts file:

```
    constructor(...) {
     ...
    samplefuncion(null){
       asyncFunction().then(()=>{
    ...//after success call
    ...
    if (event)    
    event.complete();

    },(error)=>{
    ....
    if (event)
    event.complete();
    })
    }

         doRefresh(event) {
            samplefuncion(event);        
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to follow a common convention, I have found a very easy way to reload the current view (including all of its parameters). I tested this using Ionic3, but it should still apply in Ionic 2

Move all of your initialization code for every page into `ionViewDidLoad()`, which is run ONCE on the first time the view is loaded

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Api } from '../../providers/api';
import { Movie } from '../../interfaces/movie';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-movie-info',
    templateUrl: 'movie-info.html'
})
export class MovieInfoPage {

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public navParams: NavParams,
        public api: Api
    ) {
    }

    /**
     * Run all page initialization in this method so that this page
     * can be refreshed simply by re-calling this function
     */
    ionViewDidLoad() {
        //access any parameters provided to the page through navParams. 
        var movieId = this.navParams.data.movieId;
        this.api.movies.getById(movieId).then((movie) => {
            this.movie = movie;
        });
    }
    public movie: Movie;
}
```

From anywhere else in the app, you can reload the current view with this code

```typescript
//get the currently active page component
var component = this.navController.getActive().instance;
//re-run the view load function if the page has one declared
if (component.ionViewDidLoad) {
    component.ionViewDidLoad();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
  <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>

</ion-content>
```

TypeScript :

```
@Component({...})
export class NewsFeedPage {

  doRefresh(refresher) {
    console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      refresher.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }

}
```

source : [Ionic doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just pop one page and then push that page again.

```
this.navCtrl.pop(); 
this.navCtrl.push(NewPage);
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -2):

Try this: `$window.location.reload(); $route.reload() use to reload route.`

if you are using `$stateProvider : $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true})`;

or

```
var currentPageTemplate = $route.current.templateUrl;
$templateCache.remove(currentPageTemplate);
$route.reload();
```