# reload the template(child -- /app.live_tracking ) with its parent(/app) in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In myproject  I've an app with different modules, which is organized into a single page.

I used `$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider` for routing through different pages by a side menu.

**Problem Statement:**

I use `$http` for the API request, for one condition I need to reload the whole page(which means both parent and child together)

I have tried the following and the issues are

1)    `$state.go('app');`

```
  $state.go('app.live_tracking',null,{reload:true});
```

**Problem:** This approach is get blocked saying cannot do for parent which abstract"

2) `$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});`

ref:[Clear History and Reload Page on Login/Logout Using Ionic Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192172/force-view-to-reload-in-ionic-framework)

**Problem:** reload the current route alone not the parent(menu is not loaded)

3) `$route.reload():`

ref:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703215/how-to-reload-or-re-render-the-entire-page-using-angularjs)
**Problem:** reload the current route alone not the parent(menu is not loaded)

4) `$state.transitionTo('app.live_tracking', $state.$current.params, {reload: true});`

**Problem:** reload the current route alone not the parent(menu is not loaded)

I'm here terribly stuck with this, someone kindly give me a hint to solve

Thanks in advance