# I am trying to refresh a page on success in angularjs controller.

Tags: angularjs

I have tried using $state but nothing happens. I am new to angular

```
       $http({
             method:'PUT',
             url: '/api/resources,
             data:dataObject,
             headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            AppAlert.add('success', 'The appointment was updated successfully.', 5000);
            $state.go('.', {}, {reload: true});
```

Comment: `window.location.reload()`

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand in angular it is not a good idea

Comment: Well if you're looking to refresh the whole page, meaning losing app state, which is what the OP asked for, this is the closest thing that comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `$route.reload()` to reload the current route or `$window.location.reload()` to perform a full refresh

you just need to inject those services.

[AngularJs: Reload page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885518/angularjs-reload-page)

Comment: Thanks! It worked and also what if I want to stay on the same page on refresh. In my case I am being redirected to the default page on refresh

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `ui-router` so you want to use

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
});
```