# $window.location.reload no longer working android 4.4+ Ionic Angular

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

The app is built using the ionic framework.

Its been installed on a new device that's using Android 4.4.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885518/angularjs-reload-page) I used this code to reload the page:

```
$scope.reloadRoute = function() {
   $window.location.reload();
}
```

This does not appear to work in Android 4.4+

I  have tried the other suggestions from that answer, but they do not work for our case.

I tried this:

```
location.href = location.origin;
```

It doesn't work.  I need it to reload.