# AngularJS reload page in href

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to reload  when clicking the href.

```
<li><a ng-href="#/detailedView">DetailedView</a></li>
```

so i have added the below method in controller js.

```
$scope.reloadRoute = function() {
$state.reload();
}
```

and modified the href like below, but still its not reloading.

```
<li><a ng-click="reloadRoute()" ng-href="#/detailedView">DetailedView</a></li>
```

i have tried `$route.reload();` as well, but the page is not getting refreshed while clicking the href

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885518/angularjs-reload-page ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using ui-router?

In that case you can use a statement like this from the html:

`<a ui-sref="<state-name-for-detailed-view>" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">DetailedView</a>`

And that should reload the page.  More info [here](http://%3Ca%20ui-sref=%22home%22%20ui-sref-opts=%22%7Breload:%20true%7D%22%3EHome%3C/a%3E)

There are some other options on [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885518/angularjs-reload-page)