# How to refresh the page upon successful submission using angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, angularjs, django

Hi how to refresh an html page upon successful submission?
 I've tried as follows, but its not working.

```
$scope.submit =function(){
        data = {};
        angular.extend(data, $scope.final_data);
        angular.extend(data, { checks : $scope.final_data.checks });
        $http.post('{% url 'submit' %}', data).success(
            function(data){
                alert('succesfully submitted');
                $location.path('{% url 'orc_checkbinning' %}');
            }).error(function(){
                alert('not submitted');
        })
    };
```

Am using Django framework for my project. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than refresh the page or anything like that you could probably just update it with the new data by updating your viewmodel/scope

Comment: I agree with @ExplosionPills since angular has dual binding property or you can just use location.reload() on your function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Definition and Usage**
>   The `reload()` method is used to reload the current document.
>   The `reload()` method does the same as the reload button in your browser.
>   By default, the `reload()` method reloads the page from the cache, but you can force it to reload the page from the server by setting the forceGet parameter to true: location.reload(true).
>
> Use this updated code.

```
$scope.submit =function(){
        data = {};
        angular.extend(data, $scope.final_data);
        angular.extend(data, { checks : $scope.final_data.checks });
        $http.post('{% url 'submit' %}', data).success(
            function(data){
                alert('succesfully submitted');
                   $scope.reloadPage = function()                                                
                   {
                     $window.location.reload();
                   }
                }).error(function(){
                    alert('not submitted');
            })
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best, is update the scope with the data submited, but
If you really wants refresh the page, try this:

> You can use the reload method of the $route service. Inject $route in
>   your controller and then create a method reloadRoute on your $scope.

```
$scope.reloadRoute = function() {
   $route.reload();
}
```

[SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885518/angularjs-reload-page)

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my onSubmit method in my component (after clearing the form and giving success message):

```
window.location.reload();
```