# URL redirect and reload not working in Safari and IE

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, redirect, cross-browser

I am using the following method to redirect to the `Item` page and do a full page reload too. Works in all browsers, but Safari and IE (as always!). In those two, the current page gets reloaded.

Any recommendations on how to do it differently?

```
<a href="/items/{{item.$id}}" onclick="location.reload()" class="btn">Item</a>
```

I have also tried it in JS as follows, but the same problem occurs in Safari and IE

```
$scope.redirect = function(Item) {
     window.location.href = '/items/' + item.$id;
     window.location.reload(); 
}
```

Comment: do you have the same thing if you use `ng-href`?

Comment: try this window.location.reload(); plz its work for me once

Comment: Try wrapping window.location.reload(); to force running that line of code in the next digest cycle: `$timeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); });`

Comment: are you using ui-router?

Comment: @DDT, I'm using ng-route, html5 enabled

Comment: thanks for the comments. `ng-href` solves the problem for the IE, but not for Safari. Also, still trying to understand the problem with the JS code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // put all your js inside it
 init();
});
```

also try by disabling cache parameter

Answer (score 0):

To do it the way that you are doing, you should use the angular `$window` rather than `window` while in an angular controller. A good example of reloading the route or the whole window is here: [AngularJs: Reload page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885518/angularjs-reload-page)

---

Alternatively I would consider have a button on the page:

```
<button ng-click="goItem(item.$id)" class="btn">Item</button>
```

which calls the action on the controller with the id as a parameter:

```
$scope.goItem = function(id){
    $location.path('/items/' + id );
};
```

and redirects to the specific item route.

Comment: thanks Matt, but `$location.path` would not do the reload for me. how about that part? also, the problem in Safari and IE is not that the page is not reloaded. It's that instead of the new redirected page, the previous one gets reloaded