# Need to refresh angular app on button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I started to create a single page application that takes the input from a text box and shows up to another page. On the second page I wanted to create a home button that takes me to the original view but also refreshes the application the input box to a blank state.

first view

```
<input type="text" id="Bad" style="text-transform:uppercase"  ng-model="name" />
```

second view

```
<h3>Hello</h3>
<span ng-bind="name"></span></br>
<a href="#" ng-click="reload()">
    <img src="Home_Icon.png" height="92" />
</a>
```

app .js controllers

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/second', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
        controller: 'secondController'
    });
});
```

controller fuunction

```
myApp.controller('secondController', [
    '$scope', 
    '$log', 
    '$routeParams', 
    '$window', 
    'nameService', 
    function ($scope, $log, $routeParams,  nameService) {

        $scope.num = $routeParams.num || 1;
        $scope.name = nameService.name;
        $scope.$watch('name', function () {
            nameService.name = $scope.name;
        });

        $scope.reload = function () {
            location.reload();
        }
    }]
);
```

I have tried [How to reload a page using Angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780620/how-to-reload-a-page-using-angularjs). as well. Please Help!. Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to clear the input when you navigate back to the original view?

Comment: Essential yes. I wanted to create multiple pages with an option to go home

Comment: You could set your defaults in angular and then on the button click (ng-click) use $scope.$apply() to 'refresh' the data back it's defaults

Comment: using location.reload() is a really bad practice since, it will reload all your services, controllers and scripts. I would recommend you to have that specific state reload rather than reloading the location itself. i.e, better use $stateProvider that comes with ui.routing as for your case.

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your reload function

```
$scope.name = '';
$scope.$apply();
window.location.replace('pages/first.html'); //your first page
```

Comment: Yea this didn't work.the instead it blocked the content that is typed in the input on the first page.Would it be possible to grab the binded info and reset it from another controller?