# How to restart angular app without page reload?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to reset the state of my angular app without forcing a page refresh.  What's the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703215/how-to-reload-or-re-render-the-entire-page-using-angularjs?

Comment: What state do you want to reset?  In one application I built; we provided each screen/aspect of the app a reset method which would reset the state of the view.  When the user logged out; we would 'reset' all the views and load the login screen.  Tedious, but functional.  In another app I built; we forced a reload of the app. Much easier; but not as elegant.

Comment: @JeffryHouser I want to reset all state.  As if when the page was reloaded.  I understand reloading the route forces the view to rerender, and create new instances of related controllers.  I'm interested in resetting all services as well.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if there's an idiomatic way, but if you use manual bootstrap (ie, get rid of ng-app), then to reset you could

1. Remove the element that you bootstrapped angular into
2. Replace it with a clean copy of the element
3. Run bootstrap again

Example HTML:

```
<div id="myid" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="i = i+1">Add 1</button>
  <span>i = {{i}}</span>
  <button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
</div>
```

Example controller/JS (with jQuery included as well), which would be run on onload:

```
var $cleanCopy = $("#myid").clone();

function bootstrap() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('myid'), ['mymodule']);
}

angular.module('mymodule', []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.i = 1; 

  $scope.reset = function() {
    // You need this second clone or angular bootstraps
    // into the original clone!
    $("#myid").replaceWith($cleanCopy.clone());
    bootstrap();
  };
});

bootstrap();
```

Here is a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zd377/2/

Comment: This doesn't work and the fiddle no longer contains the same code.

Comment: I did all 3 points but got an error that element was already bootstrapped.