# AngularJS – $route.reload() not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to reload page using `$route.reload()`:

```
var App = angular.module("App", ["ngRoute"]);  
var idx = 0;  

App.controller("List", function ($scope, $route) {
    $scope.changeWallet = function (index) {
        idx = index;
        $route.reload();
        console.log("success");
    };
}
```

`"success"` is shown in console, but nothing happens.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using ui-router ?

Comment: So Do you want to refresh template only ?

Comment: Remove template from cache first then try to reload the template.add this "var currentPageTemplate = $route.current.templateUrl;
$templateCache.remove(currentPageTemplate);" before reload function call.

Comment: I got `undefined is not an object (evaluating '$route.current.templateUrl')`

Comment: I don't believe it is anything to do with template cache. @supertrall You you want to reload the view partial or the complete page?

Comment: @Chandermani the complete page.

Comment: Solution described at http://stackoverflow.com/a/35139326/661414 worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to reload the complete page instead of route refresh inject the `$window` service and call location.refresh

`$window.location.reload();`

Comment: That will refresh all page, such as F5, useless for async pages.

Answer (score 3):

The $window.location.reload() will basically refresh the page like when you're pressing F5 for refresh.

What I am after is reload the specific views in the page not refreshing the entire page.