# Angularjs re-render the whole page [ionic]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, ionic-framework

I have an angular method deleteConfirm:

```
$scope.deleteConfirm = function(pageIndex) {
    var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: 'Delete Page',
        template: 'Are you sure you want to delete this page?'
    });
    confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
        if(res) {
            var permanentStorage = window.localStorage;
            var noteBooks = JSON.parse(permanentStorage["noteBooks"]);
            noteBooks[noteBookIndex].pages.splice(pageIndex, 1);
            permanentStorage["noteBooks"] = JSON.stringify(noteBooks);
        }
    });
};
```

I want to re-render the whole page after calling this function. I tried the reload() method but it didn't work for me.

Comment: `$window.location.reload()`  ?

Comment: or `$route.reload()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reload or re-render the entire page using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703215/how-to-reload-or-re-render-the-entire-page-using-angularjs)

Comment: For some reason those methods don't seem to work with ionic.

Comment: you mean like reset your app and loose all your states?

Comment: No just reloading the current page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could user following if you are using UI-Router on Ionic

```
        $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
```

Or If you are using only Angular Routes, Use follwoing

```
        $route.reload()
```