# on `refresh` getter error message as 'Cannot GET` the page, how to fix it?

Tags: angularjs

I have a login form, once the user filled the `username` and `password` i am redirecting them to `home` page.

for that i do like this:

```
$scope.submitLogin = function (valid) {

        if(!valid) return;

        var data = $scope.login;
        $location.url('/home'); //redirecting to home page.

    }
```

works fine. But after landing to that page, in case of `refresh` the page, the url is still exist as `http://localhost:3000/home` - but instead of loading the page i am getting message as `Cannot GET /home` - what is the problem here?

How to fix this? or what is the mistake i do here? any one help me to sort this please?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Here is my root provider for reference:

```
(function () {

    "user strict";

    angular.module("tcpApp", ["ngRoute","ngResource", "ngAnimate"])

    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $routeProvider
            .when ("/", {
                templateUrl : "views/login/login.html",
                controller  : "loginController"
        });

        $routeProvider
            .when ("/home", {
                templateUrl : "views/home/home.html",
                controller  : "homeController"
        });

        $routeProvider
            .otherwise ({
                redirectTo:'/'
        });
    })

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the redirecting code to:

```
$location.path('/home');
```

You're most probably running a default routing setup in which you don't have rewrites on your server setup. If so, there really is not such address. In typical basic single page application there each request to the server loads only e.g. index.html page, and the front-end routing happens by attaching `#/something` to the address.

**If you're using a html5 mode** you won't have `#` in your address, but you have to mind **you have to set up rewrites to your index file** on your server.

Comment: When i change the location like you say, my url updates like this `http://localhost:3000/#%2Fhome` nothing loading.

Comment: I have added my root provider information. I understand your point. But how can i mange with this scenario?

Comment: My mistake. Try `$location.path('/home')`

Comment: Page loads correctly, still when i refresh page disappears and getting error message as like i said.

Comment: What does the address bar show? It should be something like: `http://localhost:8000/#/home`

Comment: I seen here is a question, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703215/how-to-reload-or-re-render-the-entire-page-using-angularjs` - do i need to do something like this? if so how?

Comment: OOH. That explains a bit :) Do you handle rewrites server-side? Or is it a simple static files server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81152/discussion-between-user2024080-and-tomek-sulkowski).

Comment: This is a simple server side, i am using `connect` static server.

Comment: you have to either turn html5 mode off or make your server rewrite each request to your index.html page. Other way the server will try to find `/home` resource (e.g. `/home/index.html` on your filesystem).

Comment: Yes, understand. But I am happy if you suggest a way to `rewrite` my server each time the page reloads.