# How do I refresh a page / view in angular from a different one?

Tags: angularjs

I`m new to angularJS. So if I have this design app:

```
MainView.html(Controller1)

    SecondView.html(Controller2)

        3rdView1.html(Controller3.1)     3rdView2.html(Controller3.2)
```

How do I refresh the MainView.html, from Controler 3.1 / 3.2 ?
I tried $location.path and didn`t work. Any advice ?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? I suspect there's something in MainView that should be bound to a service shared by the other controllers of 3rdView1 and 3rdView2

Comment: Use the $routeProvider and the ng-view...

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$window.location = '/';
```

(inject $window on your controller)

Answer (score 0):

[How to reload or re-render the entire page using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703215/how-to-reload-or-re-render-the-entire-page-using-angularjs)

> $route.reload() will reinitialise the controllers but not the services. If you want to reset the whole state of your application you can use:

```
$window.location.reload();
```