# $location.path same url not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, redirect

Below is my code:

```
app.controller('lookupMasterController', [
    '$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', '$modal', 'lookupService', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, $modal, lookupService) {

$scope.openCreatePopup = function () {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/popups/add-lookup.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $location, $routeParams, lookupService) {
                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $modalInstance.close();
                }

                $scope.addLookup = function () {
                    $scope.lookup.lookUpConfigId = $routeParams.lookupMasterId;
                    lookupService.save($scope.lookup).$promise.then(
                        function (value) {
                            $location.path('/edit-lookup/' + $routeParams.lookupMasterId);
                        $scope.$apply();// Even this is not working.
                        // Tried the below as well:
                        //$scope.$apply(function () {
                          //      $location.path('/edit-lookup/' + //$routeParams.lookupMasterId);
                           // });

                            $modalInstance.close();
                        },
                    function (error) { /*Do something with error*/
                        alert(error.message);
                    });
                }
            },
            size: 'lg'
        });
    }
}
]);
```

I am opening a Popup for add new lookup and then reloading the page to see the changes. But the problem is : `$location.path('url');` is not working.

Comment: use $route.reload() in order to reload the current page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703215/how-to-reload-or-re-render-the-entire-page-using-angularjs

Comment: Not working as well..

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$state` service in that case. Try

```
$state.go('/edit-lookup/' + $routeParams.lookupMasterId);
```

Don't forget to inject `$state` in your controller initilization. Plus in your module definition you need to pass 'ui.router' as a dependency :

```
E.g. angular.module('my_app', ['ui.router'])
```

**EDIT**

I think you didn't load `ui-router.min` in your web page. Please load it just after `angular.js`

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will reload the whole page which is not what is wanted in Single Page Application. So I don't want to try this.

Comment: Error: Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state

Comment: I am not using states in my app. Now it gave this error: Could not resolve '/edit-lookup/7' from state ''