# reload page in angular js after logout

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, ngroute

Hi guys am a beginner in mean stack development I have tried to refresh the page after logout.I have tried `location.reload()`; but it doesn't work tell me the possible code for page reload in this scenario

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {
    var storage = userService.isLoggedIn();
    console.log(storage);

    if (!storage) {
        console.log('DENY');
        $rootScope.adminlogin = "adminlogin";
        console.log($rootScope.adminlogin);

        $location.path('/login');
        $route.reload();      
       // $state.go('/login', null, {reload: true});
    }
    else {
        console.log('ALLOW');
        $rootScope.admindashboard = "admindashboard";
         var path = $location.path();
          console.log(path);
          console.log(storage);
         if(path == '/login'){
            $location.path('/');
         }


    }
});
```

Comment: `$state.go('/login', null, {reload: true})` line won't work ???

Comment: i didn't used $state i used routes for redirect

Comment: Use `$window.location.reload()` [reload page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703215/how-to-reload-or-re-render-the-entire-page-using-angularjs)

Comment: use `$route.reload(); `

Comment: If you reload in the `$routeChangeStart` handler, you will create an infinite loop. That is probably what you meant when you said "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is this little line of Vanilia JS: 
            `document.location.href=document.location.href`

EDIT: why is this getting downvoted?

Answer (score 4):

You should use `$window.location.reload()` from the the [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) service if you want to refresh the page. It does the same thing as the reload button in your browser.

The reason you should use the [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) service instead of directly accessing the native [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object as per the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window):

> While window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes
>   testability problems, because it is a global variable. In AngularJS we
>   always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be
>   overridden, removed or mocked for testing.

On a side note as you stated you are using the [`$route`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) service, just calling [`$route.reload()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#reload) will only reload your controllers and not your entire application.

Comment: can you tell me where could place it.I have placed it in controller when i call login page it again again reloading

Comment: You can place it wherever you want as long as the `$window` service is made available. I'm sorry, I've told you _how_ to refresh the page, but it's up to you to know _when_ you want to refresh the page and _where_ you want to place the code to do so, you should know that :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using routes, then on click of Logout just route it to your login page.

Snap shot from demo:

these are my routes:

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/authentication/views/login.html',
            hideMenus: true
        })

        .when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'modules/home/views/home.html'
        })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
```

and when i click on 'Logout' on my page it should do somehting like:

```
<p><a href="#/login">Logout</a></a></p>
```

it should redirect to login page as per routes.