# How to reload whole page in AngularJS through Module.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state

I want to reload the whole page through `module.js`.

**Calling controller**

```
 $state.go("app.home");
```

---

```
 $stateProvider
        .state('app.home', {
            url: '/home',
            data: {
                title: 'About'
            },
            views: {
                "content@app": {
                    templateUrl: 'app/home/views/home.html',
                    controller: 'HomeController'
                }
            }
        })
```

Now I'm using location.reload for reloading the page. But when I putted **location.reoload** in **HomeController** then it is reloading infinite time. That's why I want to reload only first time my page through `$stateprovider`. I've seen one link [How to reload or re-render the entire page using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703215/how-to-reload-or-re-render-the-entire-page-using-angularjs).
 But I'm not able to solve my problem, Because I want to reload the page through **Module.js**.
And `$state.reload();` is refresh the state not reload the page.

Comment: Please explain `reload only first time` with more details. What is the definition of "first time" in your case?

Comment: When I navigate to HomeController controller this controller reload only first time.

Comment: Because when I putted location.reload in HomeController then it is reloading infinite time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save a "first time state" in a `cookie` param to ensure its only reloaded the "first time" to prevent your infinite loop. Put this stuff inside your **HomeController** controller:

```
if (!$cookies.get('firsttime')) {
  $cookies.put('firsttime', true);
  $window.location.reload();
}
```

**>> [Demo plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/hE93uROPTfPTekPyXR7w?p=preview)** (The about view gets reloaded on "firsttime")

Comment: Could you explain meaning of--> You could save a "first time state"