# AngularJS - how to use ng-click without submitting the form?

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-click, ng-submit

I have a form that has both ng-click and ng-submit.

ng-submit is meant for the submission, while ng-click calls a separate function like upload, etc.

How do I make sure that ng-click does not accidentally submits the form?

thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319758/angularjs-clicking-a-button-within-a-form-causes-page-refresh

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`ngClick` *does not* submit the form.

Sometimes, you can have problems because you have two `button` elements in your `form`, and they both submit it. To avoid that, specify the type `"button"` on it. Example :

```js
function demo ($scope) {
  
  $scope.doSubmit = function () {
    alert('I submit');
  };
  
  $scope.doClick = function () {
    alert('I click');
  };
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="demo">
  
  <form ng-submit="doSubmit()">
    <button type="button" ng-click="doClick()">click</button>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
  
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! adding in the type="button" to all my buttons solve the problem!

Comment: Could be surmised as just adding the attribute `type="button"` on the `<button>` element. Thanks for the fix!