# How to stop page refresh on typing in Form input?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm breaking my head over a small issue. I have a chat box in my web app which contains one input[type='text'] and a button. What I want is whenever user clicks on the button, the corresponding message is sent to server and clears the input field on button click.

I'm facing an issue where when a user types in input[type='text'], it causes my controller to refresh. Also, on clicking the button, the controller refreshes.

I have found few threads which mention similar problem but somehow the solution mentioned in these thread is not working for me.

[AngularJS, clicking a button within a form causes page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319758/angularjs-clicking-a-button-within-a-form-causes-page-refresh)

Following is my code:

```
<form name="form">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type Message ..." ng-model="form.newMessage" class="form-control"/><span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" ng-click="submitNewMessage()" class="btn btn-info btn-flat">Send</button></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Can anyone please help with this?

Thanks

**Update:**

Based on the suggested solutions I modified my code. But it is still not wokring:

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="submitNewMessage()">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type Message ..." ng-model="form.newMessage" class="form-control"/><span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-flat">Send</button></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
$scope.submitNewMessage = function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log($scope.form.newMessage);

}
```

Also, my doubt is even on writing anything in the input box, it refreshes the page. Why is it so ? Shouldn't it wait till I submit the form ?

Update 2: It seems the actual problem is different from this. I have created a different question and this might solve this problem as well. Can anyone please tale a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732258/view-is-getting-intialized-again-and-again)?
Thanks

Comment: What does your Angular code look like?

Comment: @Mr.Concolato: I have uupdated my controller code. Please take  a look at it

Comment: Can you add a working Plunker of this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the submition of the form, you have to add an event.preventDefault() to your submitNewMessage function.

Other way is to remove the form tags.

Comment: You suggested solution is not working. Please refer to my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the page from reloading when you click the button, try this:

```js
$scope.submitNewMessage = function($event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // your code
$scope.form.newMessage = ''; // to empty your input afterwards
}
```