# Why does ngSubmit bind to all buttons in the form

Tags: typescript, angular-forms

Hello i have a `ngForm` and i want to be able to add to it a couple of `buttons` with various functionality.However i also need a `submit` button that takes all the  state of the form and sends it to a handler.

My problem is that if i add other buttons in the form , the `ngSubmit` handler is called on all of them ( after their specific callbacks)

**Example**

```
 <form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit_Handler()">
    <button id="x_btn" (click)="x_Handler()">X</button>
    <button id="y_btn" (click)="y_Handler()">Y</button>
    <button id="z_btn" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

If i press on the last button `z_btn` the `submit_Handler` will get called.However if i press on the first two buttons (`x` and `y` , first their callbacks are called (`x_Handler` and `y_Handler`) but then the `submit_Handler` is also called.How can i achieve separate functionality between submit and other buttons ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i am aware a `type="button"` might stop it from submiting. Might want to look into this Post https://stackoverflow.com/a/15314160/10567964

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if the button type is submit inside the form then when u click it it will postback the entire page/form same is happening in angular too. since, inside a form u put the all the buttons and bind them into an single ngsubmit that's why its calling each time.

In my suggestion u have to remove that ngsubmit from that form and put that inside z_button, then it will call only when u click z_button, else it will not call.

thnx

Comment: I though the `ngSubmit` directive has to be set on the form to be able to gain all the data.