# Adding rows in the table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have one form which has master detail data. i have created one table for details and creating rows on button click using JavaScript, but as soon as i am clicking add row button it is adding row and immediately my page gets reloaded so the added row disappears. i have another buttons to perform other PHP tasks so i can not remove form tag. please help me to get this done.
following is the HTML and JavaScript code.

```
<div class="row pt-3">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table id="vattable" class="table table-sm table-striped">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                      <tr>
                        <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"VATSETUP","VSDID"); ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"VATSETUP","VSDSCATEGORY"); ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"VATSETUP","VSDRATE"); ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo GetBilingualLabels($_SESSION['$language'],"VATSETUP","VSDAUTOFLAG"); ?></th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" class="text-control input-sm" readonly name="vsdid[]" id="vsdid" value=1 style="text-align:right" maxlength="13" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="text-control" name="vsdscategory[]" id="vsdscategory1" style="text-align:right" maxlength="13" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="text-control" name="vsdrate[]" id="vsdrate1" style="text-align:right" maxlength="13" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="vsdautoflag[]" id="vsdautoflag1" style="text-align:right" maxlength="13" autofocus /></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    var count=1;
    $(document).on('click','#addrow', function(){
      //alert('a');
      count=count+1;
      $('#vsdid').val(count);
      //alert(count);
      var html_code='';
      html_code +='<tr id="row_id_'+count+'">';
      html_code += '<td><input type="text" class="text-control input-sm" name="vsdid[]" id="vsdid'+count+'" style="text-align:right"/></td>';
      html_code +='<td><input type="text" class="text-control" name="vsdscategory[]" id="vsdscategory'+count+'" /></td>';
      html_code +='<td><input type="text" class="text-control" name="vsdrate[]" id="vsdrate'+count+'" style="text-align:right" maxlength="13" /></td>';
      html_code +='<td><input type="text" name="vsdautoflag[]" id="vsdautoflag'+count+'" style="text-align:right" /></td>';
      html_code +='<td><button type="submit" name="removerow" id="removerow" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-minus"></button></td></tr>';
      $('#vattable').append(html_code);
      //alert(html_code);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It's possible that your `#addrow` button is the submit button and the form is being submitted. Add a `return false` just after `//alert(html_code)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working now.

Comment: how can i make it resolved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clicking a button within a form causes page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319758/clicking-a-button-within-a-form-causes-page-refresh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your `#addrow` button is the submit button and the form is being submitted. Add a `return false` just after `//alert(html_code)`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added a button to add the rows, so you're likely observing a side effect.

If I understand correctly, you want to have a button that on click will execute the function you've created. Therefore, you can add a button with id `addrow` below the table div like this:

```
 <button id="addrow">
    Add Row
 </button>
```

And then you can attach your function via jQuery as you've started (I have slightly amended your script) - see JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9Ljc237k/9/

Answer (score 0):

in your add row button click you should `return false` at the end,
or set type attribute of your button tag to `button` instead of `submit`

also is better to append row to `tbody` tag not `table`

Answer (score -2):

If you have the problem only with reload you should put event.preventDefault()

```
 $(document).on('click','#addrow', function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
      //alert('a');
      count=count+1;
      $('#vsdid').val(count);
      //alert(count);
      var html_code='';
      html_code +='<tr id="row_id_'+count+'">';
      html_code += '<td><input type="text" class="text-control input-sm" name="vsdid[]" id="vsdid'+count+'" style="text-align:right"/></td>';
      html_code +='<td><input type="text" class="text-control" name="vsdscategory[]" id="vsdscategory'+count+'" /></td>';
      html_code +='<td><input type="text" class="text-control" name="vsdrate[]" id="vsdrate'+count+'" style="text-align:right" maxlength="13" /></td>';
      html_code +='<td><input type="text" name="vsdautoflag[]" id="vsdautoflag'+count+'" style="text-align:right" /></td>';
      html_code +='<td><button type="submit" name="removerow" id="removerow" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-minus"></button></td></tr>';
      $('#vattable').append(html_code);
      //alert(html_code);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its working with both commands as first answer return false as well as second answer event.preventDefault();

Comment: in addition to this i am adding one more button to remove record inside the JavaScript add row as follows.. html_code +='<td><button type="button" name="removerow" id="'+count+'" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-remove"></button></td></tr>'; and i have written another JavaScript function to remove row but it is not working $(document).on('click','.removerow',function(){
      var row_id=$(this).attr("id");
      $('#row_id_'+row_id).remove;
      count=count-1;
    });

Comment: Bear in mind that this approach is only a hack - a fix without understanding the problem and not taking into consideration best practices.  It's likely the button is a submit form button and you're preventing the default action - submitting the form. Instead, I think it's better to create a plain button outside the form and attach an onclick add row action to it.

Comment: Thanks if i change the type from "submit" to "button", it is working without adding either of the above commands. please look into my another comment section regarding remove row.

Comment: remove is a function so you have to do $('#row_id_'+row_id).remove(); but you can also try $('#vattable').remove('#row_id_'+row_id)

Comment: i wrote it like that but the function is not executing at all. i tried to put alert to check whether function is executing or not but no response. This is the function to remove row.....  $(document).on('click','.removerow',function(){
      var row_id=$(this).attr("id");
      /*$('#row_id_'+row_id).remove;
      count=count-1;*/
      alert('a');
    });

Comment: html_code +='<td><button type="submit" name="removerow" id="removerow" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-minus"></button></td></tr>'
So here you forgot to add removerow in class attr you class attr should be like this class="btn btn-danger fa fa-minus removerow".