# Using a button with JavaScript & HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

I know, the title seems to lead to a repetitive/useless question, but I can't find a solution in other questions. Let me explain better and read what follows before closing my question.

I created a form by learning from different sources. It all seems to work fine, until I have to click on submit button, with "Save as TXT" written on it. It happens quite a strange thing:

- if I click on the text "Save as TXT" inside the button, it submits my data correctly;
- if I click on the coloured part around the text "Save as TXT" of the button, it refreshes the page.

I think I found why this happens, but I can't fix it. It seems to be something which has to do with both my HTML code and my JavaScript code. Here it is a part of it:

*Javascript*

```
$(function(){
    $("#submitLink").click(function(event){

       // things to do on submit...

});
});
```

*HTML*

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" action="" id="formToSave">

    <!-- some fields to compile... -->

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="align" type="submit"><a href="javascript://Save as TXT" id="submitLink">Save as TXT</a></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I change this part of the code in order to submit successfully by clicking anywhere on the button (and do what I write in the JS function)?

Thanks in advance,

happy coding everyone!

ps. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319758/clicking-a-button-within-a-form-causes-page-refresh) "famous" question you added by after closing my question, but it is not helping me. By writing `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` I get no results, I'm sorry

Comment: `javascript://Save as TXT` is not a valid URL and will generate JavaScript errors trying to process it because `Save as TXT` is not valid JavaScript. Hint: do not use the, `javascript://` pseudo protocol, and avoid antiquated tutorials still using it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need for the BUTTON type `'button'` but you had 'submit'. So it wants to submit the form which follows in a reloading, with button the action is needed to be done from you.
The A-tag is not needed so I deleted it. On the contrary if clicked at the corners anything happened, now this functions

```
<button type="button" id='btn'>Save as TXT</button>
```

Just test it.

```js
$(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(event){
        console.log('Submit');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" name="myForm" action="" id="formToSave">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="btn" type="button">Save as TXT</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: At first I thought this was the best solution, but I'm sorry it's still not working. For example, if I click on a corner of your button it still doesn't work.

Comment: You are right, the A-tag was disturbing. After deleteing from it, it works on the corner too.

Answer (score 1):

> - if I click on the text "Save as TXT" inside the button, it submits my data correctly;

When you click on the text itself, you are clicking the `<a>` element, and therefore triggering its event listener.

> - if I click on the coloured part around the text "Save as TXT" of the button, it refreshes the page.

When you click on any part of the button, are triggering the `<button>`'s event listener.

Therefore, I suggest

So it seems like the solution is to taking the `<a>` element's event listener and attaching it to the `<button>`.

One way to do this is to replace

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="align" type="submit"><a href="javascript://Save as TXT" id="submitLink">Save as TXT</a></button>
```

with

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="align" onclick="{Save as TXT}" type="button">Save as TXT</button>
```

where "{Save as TXT}" was the code you previously had in the `<a>`'s `href`.

The reason you need to add `type="button"` is so you can disable the button's default behavior submitting the form (and therefore refreshing the page).

Then, since you got rid of the `<a>` tag, you need to attach any  listeners that used to listen for clicks on the `<a>` tag to the `<button>` instead.

To do this, replace:

```js
$("#submitLink").click(function(event){

    // things to do on submit...

});
```

with

```js
$("#align").click(function(event){

    // things to do on submit...

});
```

**See it in action:**

```html
<form method="post" name="myForm" action="" id="formToSave">

    <!-- some fields to compile... -->

    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="align" onclick="console.log('Submitted')" type="button">Save as TXT</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you're right, but for some reason if I do what you suggest it just refreshes the page whenever I click on the text or on the button :/

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add `type="button"` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836076/7215455). I fixed it.

Comment: Ok, this will seem weird, but with ```type="button"``` now gives this error: ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier```. Your code is perfect...

Comment: Could I see the rest of your code?

Comment: Sure... can you start a chat? I still haven't enough points to do it

Comment: Sure: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220178/question-63513072-chat

Comment: Can we delete the chat and the code from it? Sorry if I'm posting this here, but I'd prefer not to have it online yet

Comment: I looked at the Chat FAQ, and I don't think it's possible to delete chat rooms.

Comment: ok, noprob, thanks again :)