# Jquery - how to add a click event for each button

Tags: jquery

Using the below jquery, I am able to find each button with the id, what I can't get to happen is when I lick the button to actually load the URL.  How can I modify the jquery so when I click the button it will before the load?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("_Research", "Dashboard")';
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
    buttons.forEach(
        function (currentBtn) {
            alert(currentBtn.id);
            currentBtn.click(function() {
                $('#researchDiv').load(url, {
                    ticker: currentBtn.id
                })
            });
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: since you're using jquery you should `$(currentBtn)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you don't need a loop. The jQuery event binding method automatically loops over all the elements. Then you can use `this` to refer to the button that was clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = '@Url.Action("_Research", "Dashboard")';
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    $('#researchDiv').load(url, {
      ticker: this.id
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but now I don't understand why the whole page reloads the second time you click the button.

Comment: It's probably a submit button. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319758/clicking-a-button-within-a-form-causes-page-refresh

Comment: I tried <button type="button" class="btn" and it still refreshes the whole page

Comment: There's nothing in this code that will do that. Post a new question with a [mre].

Comment: even tried  <div class="btnB" id='div_@watchList.WatchListName+@watchList.UserWatchListId+@ticker.Ticker'>
                            <p class="category-title">@ticker.Ticker</p>
                        </div> and still loads the whole page

Comment: Something unrelated to this code is doing that. That's why you need to post a [mre]